# Persisting data with intellij idea, spring and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

I know this question was asked a lot but none of the solution worked for me so far.
I am working on a spring project and I need to create the database from entities.
I have structured the project and annotated my entities.
When I right-click on the project name and click "Add Framework Support..", I choose "persistence JavaEE" and Intellij loads the necessary files.
Intellij creates the META-INF folder, persistence.xml file with default configuration and I can see the persistence tool window.
I can also see my entities in the persistence unit. I have created a datasource in "Database" and tested the connection and it works fine.

The problem is when I start the server (wildFly 8.0.0) it seems that it completely ignores persistence. It starts normally without errors but it doesn't create the tables, doesn't show any information at the console about hibernate or persistence.

This is my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0"> 
    <persistence-unit name="OoredooPersistenceUnit">
         <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
         <properties>
              <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/DatabaseName"/>
              <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
              <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
              <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
              <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
              <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
              <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
              <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
         </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: The proper property name is `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`. Does persistence work, did you try to read/persist anything?

Comment: I changed the property name as you mentioned but still doesn't work. And no I need to create the tables from the classes but doesn't work, the database is empty

Comment: So, did you try to read/persist anything?

Comment: No because the tables are not even created

Comment: Could you try nevertheless, the exception stacktrace may reveal the true reason? If it complains that tables do not exist, then we know that it is `hbm2ddl` issue only.